# I can't debug JSP file in Eclipse. How can I debug Java code in my JSP file?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, debugging

I can't debug JSP in Eclipse.

I tried the following:

When I debug a **.jsp** file in my project A, it doesn't work, but I can debug **.jsp** file in my project B.

When I opened .jsp of my project and added a breakpoint in the .jsp file of project B, then I run project A using in debug mode, it works.

But its debugger is working wrong.

Is it bug of Eclipse?

**How can I debug a JSP file?**

The structures of the projects are almost same.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What's not happening that should be happening?